# Unity - Microphone check if silent

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, recording

We use the standard method of recording audio in Unity:

`_sendingClip = Microphone.Start(_device, true, 10, 16000);`

where `_sendingClip` is the AudioClip and `_device` is the device name.

I'd like to know when the user stops speaking, which can happen after 2 seconds, or even 10.

I've looked at different sources to find an answer, but could not find one:

- https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/check-current-microphone-input-volume.133501/
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/137170/how-to-check-if-the-user-speak-to-microphone.html (but this one is over 5 years old already)
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1113690/microphone-input-in-unity-5x.html

The idea is that when a user stops talking, the audio is send to a speech recognition server without a delay and without audio getting cut off when the user is still speaking.

Solutions don't need to be in code format. A general direction of where to look would be nice.

Comment: Well how do we know if a user stops talking? Probably when the amplitude of the waves dips beneath a certain threshold value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the recording audioclip to an AudioSource and play it using:

```
audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(_device, true, 60, 16000);
while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }
audioSource.Play();
```

When it is playing, you can get the SpectrumData from the audio. When the user is speaking the spectrumdata will show more peaks. You can check the average of the SpectrumData audio to determine if someone is speaking. You should set some sort of minimum level, as you will probably have some noise in the recordings. If the average of the spectrumdata is above the determined level, someone is speaking, if it's below that, the user stopped speaking.

```
float[] clipSampleData = new float[1024];
bool isSpeaking=false;

void Update(){
   audioSource.GetSpectrumData(clipSampleData, 0, FFTWindow.Rectangular);
   float currentAverageVolume = clipSampleData.Average();

   if(currentAverageVolume>minimumLevel){ 
      isSpeaking=true 
   } 
   else if(isSpeaking){
      isSpeaking=false;
      //volume below level, but user was speaking before. So user stopped speaking
   }
}
```

You can put that check in the Update method, the spectrumdata will be the spectrumdata of the last frame. So it will be close to realtime.

The minimum level can be determined by just recording something silent, you can do that before the user needs to speak, or in a set-up kind of way.

With this solution the user will hear itself speak, you can set the output of the audiosource to the audiomixer, and put that volume to -80. So it will still recognize the data, but doesn't output the sound to the user. Setting the volume to 0 on the audioSource will give 0 spectrumdata, so use the audiomixer in that case.

Comment: what would be the minimumLevel value?

Comment: That depends on the environmental sound. Let say you run it for 1 minute without talking into the mic. You can get the average `currentAverageVolume` over 1 minute, that value can be your `minimumLevel`.

Comment: i am getting approx 0.0002 value, so whenever you are silent its close to 0, if you speak something the value goes high like 5 or 7

Comment: That means that you're in a very quiet room/environment. I'd put it a bit higher, if speaking puts it a 5 or 7. 3 maybe? That also gives you a bit of room in case the environment gets a bit more noisy. (Although you could also add some sort of a step into your program that allows you to re-set the minimum level, during some sort of an initiation step in your game)

Comment: Ya, I am into quite room
Yeap need to keep some settings where I can analyze the room noise at the start and confirm the minimalLevel and proceed

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a latency when working with audio.

Are you asking to record and send a clip to the SRS every time the user stops talking? or after 'x' amount of time when no voice input has been received ? (Something to think about)

Here is a decent read on the subject : https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206485253-How-do-I-get-Unity-to-playback-a-Microphone-input-in-real-time-

Sorry I can't be of more help - hope you find a solution!