# Check microphone for silence

Tags: unity-game-engine

While recording user voice, i want to know when he/she stopped talking to end the recording and send the audio file to google speech recognition API.

I found this thread here and tried to use it's solution but i am always getting the same value  from the average of spectrum data which is 5.004574E-08:
[Unity - Microphone check if silent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913081/unity-microphone-check-if-silent)

This is the code i am using for getting the GetSpectrumData value:

```
public void StartRecordingSpeech()
    {
        //If there is a microphone
        if (micConnected)
        {
            if (!Microphone.IsRecording(null))
            {
                goAudioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 10, 44100); //Currently set for a 10 second clip max
                goAudioSource.Play();
                StartCoroutine(StartRecordingSpeechCo());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("No microphone is available");
        }
    }

IEnumerator StartRecordingSpeechCo()
    {
        while (Microphone.IsRecording(null))
        {
            float[] clipSampleData = new float[128];
            goAudioSource.GetSpectrumData(clipSampleData, 0, FFTWindow.Rectangular);
            Debug.Log(clipSampleData.Average());
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

PS: I am able to record the users voice, save it and get the right response from the voice recognition api.

Comment: Define "silent." The microphone is *always* picking up *something.*

Comment: @Draco18s when the user is not talking. In other words, if the volume of the input sound is high or low.
My goal is to get some kind of variable that indicates if the user is talking or not.

Comment: Presumably your debug statement is printing out some values, yes?

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, its always 5.004574E-08!

Comment: Not sure, then.

Answer (score 1):

The following method is what worked for me. it detect the volume of the microphone, turn it into decibels. It does not need to play the recorded audio or anything. (credit goes to this old thread in the unity answers: https://forum.unity.com/threads/check-current-microphone-input-volume.133501/).

```
    public float LevelMax()
        {
            float levelMax = 0;
            float[] waveData = new float[_sampleWindow];
            int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (_sampleWindow + 1); // null means the first microphone
            if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
            goAudioSource.clip.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
            // Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
            for (int i = 0; i < _sampleWindow; i++)
            {
                float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
                if (levelMax < wavePeak)
                {
                    levelMax = wavePeak;
                }
            }
float db = 20 * Mathf.Log10(Mathf.Abs(levelMax));
            return db;
        }
```

In my case, if the value is bigger then -40 then the user is talking!if its 0 or bigger then there is a loud noise, other then that, its silence!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a **volume** then [`GetSpectrumData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.GetSpectrumData.html) is actually not really what you want. This is used for frequency analysis and returns - as the name says - a frequency spectrum so how laud is which frequency in a given frequency range.

---

What you rather want to use is [`GetOutputData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.GetOutputData.html) which afaik returns an array with **amplitudes** from `-1` to `1`. So you have to square all values, get the average and take the square root of this result ([source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/157940/getoutputdata-and-getspectrumdata-they-represent-t.html))

```
float[] clipSampleData = new float[128];
goAudioSource.GetOutputData(clipSampleData, 0);

Debug.Log(Mathf.Sqrt(clipSampleData.Select(f => f*f).Average()));
```

Comment: Same as the GetSpectrumData, GetOutputData keep returning 0 weither i am talking or not!

Comment: Oh wait.. afaik it still returns values -1 to 1 so the avarege might not be usable directly but you probably have to use absolute values ... to be fair the documentation is really shit on these methods ^^

Comment: I am sorry i didnt fully undrestand you, if you mean the problem is with using average(), I tried removing it and instead logging clipSampleData[0] but i am still getting 0 always

Comment: Thank you, but even "Mathf.Sqrt(clipSampleData.Select(f => f*f).Average())" is always returning 0!